# Would it be possible to integrate crypto with trading bot?

Tags: exchanges, decoding, flashbots

You can create a trading bot in trading view and see how well your crypto would perform in a given time frame. (I can see how much money would I make if I didn't sell or how much money I would make if I use that code) Do you think would it be possible to create trading bot that work with crypto exchanges?

Answer (score 0):

It already exists. See [TradeSanta](https://tradesanta.com/en) for instance.

However, just so you know, if you can read about a trading strategy on the internet, you can be sure that this strategy is not profitable because many other people are already doing it.

It's even worst if a tool to do it is available such as Trade Santa. If it works, why do the developers of Trade Santa sell their software instead of just using it secretly and making billions (hint: it does not work, so there is more money to make by selling it)?

Comment: I understand, I just wanted to know if we could integrate Python (programming language) with crypto exchanges and without breaking their security.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of bots running on cryptocurrency exchanges.
Also you can see and compare the results in a specific time frame, if you would run the bot or just do HODL. It is called "BackTest". Also some crypto trading bots have "Paper Trading" option which means running as you have real money with real-time market conditions.

Some of them:
Trality
3Commas
LydianBot
HummingBot
Paratica
etc...

Answer (score 0):

Theres quite a few trading bot solutions out there - however its important to understand what the bot is doing for you, and what type of control you have over it.

I've found many bots on the market today are meant to do a specific thing, run specific strategies. And while those bots may work well when those strategies are doing well in the market - often times market climates change. If you don't have enough control over your trading bot - you could get into situations where it was profiting and now its losing.

This is why I like:
[TradeLab.ai](https://tradelab.ai)

Its a tool you can use for free that lets you make your own complex trading bots without code. Many of the strategies I was interested in were too complex for 3Commas, TradeSanta and wunderbit.

With TradeLab I'm able to send trade alerts from multiple different places, listen for alerts over time, collecting information and comparing past bars. So instead of just firing off an alert and the bot placing the trade, this allows you to combine alerts and use more data to make better decisions when the time is right.

To read more about how TradeLab.ai check here
https://tradelab.ai/?p=1304